# Filling an array of linked lists without getting an: ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, arrays

So I have this function I am trying to create which should fill an array of linked lists with an arraylist. Everytime I try to add something to the linked list, I get this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
>       at tester.Tester.addDataAry(Tester.java:35)
>       at tester.Tester.main(Tester.java:41)
>   Java Result: 1

There's other stuff in my class to do other things, so I'll just post a working version of what I am trying to do with this code:

```
package tester;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class Tester {

private int size;
private LinkedList[][] ll;
private ArrayList al;

public Tester(int size) {
    this.size = size;
    ll = new LinkedList[size][size];
}

public void addDataAry(int i, int j, String s) {
    al = new ArrayList();
    if (i >= 0 && i < size && j > 0 && j < size) {
        if (ll[i][j] == null) {
            ll = new LinkedList[i][j];
        } else if (ll[j][i] == null) {
            ll = new LinkedList[j][i];
        } else {
            ll[i][j].add(al.add(s));
        }
        ll[j][i].add(al.add(s));  // problem reported here
    }
    System.out.println(ll.toString());
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Tester test = new Tester(6);
    test.addDataAry(1, 1, "Testing");
}
}
```

Anyone have an idea as to why I keep getting the array index error, and how I can fix it? Thanks.

Comment: In one case you initialize the array with dimensions i and j. In the "else if" case you initialize it with dimensions j and i. Then the problem line is accessing it with indices i and j. Are you sure you can guarantee those dimensions are valid? Doesnt seem like it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems with your implementation.

First: You keep reassigning the ll array! This line: `ll = new LinkedList[i][j];` assigns the ll array to a NEW array of size i,j. That's why the first if passes but the second if does not. Replace every instance of `ll = new LinkedList[i][j];` with `ll[i][j] = new LinkedList(...);`

Second, these lines:

```
        if (ll[i][j] == null) {
            ll = new LinkedList[i][j];
        } else if (ll[j][i] == null) {
            ll = new LinkedList[j][i];
        } else {
            ll[i][j].add(al.add(s));
        }
```

may not do what you think they do. If you're trying to ensure that, no matter what order you use i and j to index the 2D array, you do not get a null pointer error; this won't work. If the first if passes each of the other ifs (and the last else) are skipped. You may want to remove every else if this is a problem.

Third you're using a non-generic version of ArrayList and LinkedList. This greatly reduces your type saftey and could produce several hard to track bugs.

Fourth, this line: 
    `System.out.println(ll.toString());`
Is going to cause you problems. ll is an array so you're going to get something like:
    `[[Ljava.util.LinkedList;@5a07e868`
To fix this, you need to write your own `twoDArrayToString` function. Here's a simple implementation:

```
public static String twoDArrToString(Object[][] arr) {
    System.out.println(arr.length);
    StringBuilder sb = null;
    if (arr.length > 0) {
        sb = new StringBuilder(arr.length * arr[0].length);//Making it a tiny bit more efficient
    } else {
        return "";//Doesn't make sense to have a zero length array
    }

    for (Object[] objArr : arr) {
        sb.append("[");
        for (Object obj : objArr) {
            sb.append(obj).append(", ");
        }
        sb.append("]\n");
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Also, as CyberneticTwerkGuruOrc mentioned, you're adding an ArrayList to a LinkedList. Are you trying to go 4D on us?

Hope that helps!

Comment: I did the ~System.out.println(ll.toString());~ just to see if I could get anything to print out. I usually use a nested loop to print out the contents, but am just trying to get it to work. If using an array inside a linked list array is a no-no, then how do you get an array of data inside a liked list array? Eventually, this is all going to be an adjacency list. I've managed to create a grid, I was just trying to figure out how to print it out via the adjacency list, and had seen that it is supposed to be an array of linked lists. Perhaps I misunderstood. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: It's not technically a problem, but it can get confusing. You have lists nested 4 deep, using three different types of lists (LinkedList, ArrayList, and two ordinary arrays). That might be difficult to maintain.

Answer (score 2):

There's a lot wrong here:

```
public void addDataAry(int i, int j, String s) {
    al = new ArrayList();//why are you making an arraylist?
    if (i >= 0 && i < size && j > 0 && j < size) {
        if (ll[i][j] == null) {
            ll = new LinkedList[i][j];//MAJOR ISSUE 1
        } else if (ll[j][i] == null) {//dont need this check
            ll = new LinkedList[j][i];
        } else {//dont need this because its done below
            ll[i][j].add(al.add(s));
        }
        ll[j][i].add(al.add(s));  // MAJOR ISSUE 2
    }
    System.out.println(ll.toString());
}
```

You do only need to check one index.

**MAJOR ISSUE 1:**

You want the specific 2d array point `ll[i][j]` to have an new `LinkedList`.

**MAJOR ISSUE 2:**

Why do you have an `ArrayList` being added to a 2d array of `LinkedList`s?  Also, you just need to add the input `String` to the specified `LinkedList` in the 2d array.

It should be this:

```
public void addDataAry(int i, int j, String s) {
    if (i >= 0 && i < size && j > 0 && j < size) {
        if (ll[i][j] == null) {
            ll[i][j] = new LinkedList();
        }
        ll[i][j].add(s);
    }
    System.out.println(ll.toString());//WARNING:  This only prints the address of the object!
}
```

Comment: Changed it to this: ~public void addDataAry(int i, int j, String s) {
        al = new ArrayList();
        if (i >= 0 && i < size && j > 0 && j < size) {
            if (ll[i][j] == null) {
                ll = new LinkedList[i][j];
            }
            ll[i][j].add(al.add(s));
        }
        System.out.println(ll.toString());
    }~ but still no go, same error pops up

Comment: I'm adding the array because at some point down the line, it will contain an array of strings, not just the one. Right now I'm trying to figure out how to do it with the arraylist having only one string value, to learn. Also, I was trying the double check, ([i][j] & [j][i]) because I was hoping to see if it would work in an adjacency list, (which takes a lot more than this I know, but I go with baby steps so I actually understand how to do things)